# Remove the item from ComboBox once it's been selected in the previous ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

I'm lost here, I wanna remove the item from ComboBox once it's been selected in the previous ComboBox. I have tried many approaches but didn't resolve this problem. Please help me in solving this problem and below I've included all of the code. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
ComboBox[] combo_for_constraint = new ComboBox[count];
int combo_for_constraint_x = 250, combo_for_constraint_y = 50;
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
    combo_for_constraint[i] = new ComboBox();
    combo_for_constraint[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(combo_for_constraint_x, combo_for_constraint_y + (i * 10));
    combo_for_constraint[i].Size = new Size(100, 50);
    combo_for_constraint[i].Name = "combo_for_constraintbx" + i.ToString();
    combo_for_constraint[i].DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    tabPage2.Controls.Add(combo_for_constraint[i]);
    tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
    combo_for_constraint_y += 40;
    tabPage2.Refresh();
    if (i >= 2 && combo_for_constraint[i - 1].Text == "PRIMARY KEY")
    {
        combo_for_constraint[i + 1].Items.RemoveAt(1);
    }
    else
    {
        combo_for_constraint[i].Items.Add("UNIQUE");
        combo_for_constraint[i].Items.Add("PRIMARY KEY");
        combo_for_constraint[i].Items.Add("FOREIGN KEY");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing why don't you add the three items only when i = 1 and leave the other combo with just two items? By the way, array index starts at zero. The first combo at index zero is never used and it is still empty at the end of this code

Comment: I want if I select "Primary Key" from the ComboBox the item "Primary Key" text will be removed from the ComboBoxes except for the ComboBox in which I select. Yes, there is an array index mistake.